# Can I install a second instance of linux on a spare partition without usb-disk or CD

Tags: linux, partitioning, installation, unetbootin

I have OpenSUSE (42.3) linux installed on the first partition if my hard drive and I want to install another distribution on a second partition. I do not want to use an USB drive or CD/DVD.

I've tried unetbootin which forces to install on '/', it does not allow to select e.g. /dev/sda2 as root for the new installation. Also tried Wubi, which is not available for my current distribution

Are there packages or methods which I can use to install a new linux distribution (eg from an .iso file) on a spare partition while I'm logged in on a running linux environment (let's say on /dev/sda1).

Comment: Which application is used in Arch?

Comment: Grub can boot ISO files so any distro using Grub will do. Unetbootin and Wubi are NOT tools for that task.